# Power transistor identification: Philips ON503

Tags: power, transistors, identification, automotive

I'm trying to find information on a power transistor used on a 1978 automotive ECU. Having reverse-engineered the circuit, I'm fairly certain that it's a NPN transistor, but I've found some references mentioning a Darlington transistor was used on the ECU.

The markings on the case are:

```
Philips
ON503
F8131
```

It's used to drive 4 injectors simultaneously, in this configuration:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fSBzbm.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Here's what the case looks like from the front:

[image: Philips ON503 BJT power transistor]

And here's what the pins look from the other side (they're the long metal tabs that come from the case, around the middle of the picture):

[image: Philips ON503 BJT power transistor pins]

Would someone have information on the device's characteristics, or a pointer to the datasheet?

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: I had a look in a 1974 copy of Towers' International Transistor Selector, and there's no mention of it. No transistors prefixed 'ON' at all. But there's a 1981 date code on the part, so maybe it's a newer type than the book.

Comment: @JohnHonniball, thanks for looking. Ah, so the F8131 refers to the date? I guess the 31 is the 31st week of the year, then.

Comment: Possibly equivalent to the Delco DS-503? There’s also an eastern bloc power transistor KD-503 mentioned on this WP page https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/2N3055